# Git rebase order - confusion

Tags: git

In [git-scm](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Rebasing), they say that the supposed-to-be-merged commit is moved entirely (as a new commit) to the tip of the current branch :

So, instead of a merge operation :

[image]

We go with rebase :

[image]

Notice that C3 is kept original.

However, when I looked at [git-tower](https://www.git-tower.com/learn/git/ebook/en/command-line/advanced-topics/rebase), they show that the branch is not moved to the tip but to the start :

> we want to integrate the changes from branch-B into branch-A, but now
>   by using rebase.

[image]

After rebase :

[image]

**Question:**

What's going on here?

git-scm shows that it is moved to the *tip* of the branch while git-tower shows that it's not.

Comment: Except for the fact that the git-tower illustration incorrectly shows `C3` being *moved* (rather than copied to a new `C3'`), both diagrams show the same thing. (Note that the git-scm diagram also includes, first, a hypothetical `git merge` that is then taken away again since the idea is to rebase *instead of* merging.)

Comment: @torek well, it does show a `C3*`, implying this is not the same C3.

Comment: @VonC: Ah, actually I missed the star, as it's somewhat overwritten by the circle!

Comment: The only way I will understand it is if they confused in words : https://i.imgur.com/BPVhSaZ.jpg

Comment: @RoyiNamir No: integrating branch-A into branch-B means B ancestor includes commits from A. You can do that by rebaseing B on top of A. What the example shows is the opposite: A ancestors includes commits from B: you replay A on top of B: git rebase branch-B.

Comment: @RoyiNamir: I dislike the whole idea of wording this as "integrate branch ___ into branch ___". Branch *names* just point to single commits. As a human interpreting a commit graph, we're free to extend the *graph-following* operation as far as we like, and stop wherever we like, and when we stop earlier or later, we may perceive things differently. So "integrate" is inherently going to be confusing. It's better to just draw the graph and show where the labels go.

Comment: @torek Agreed, even though I tried to explain the intent in my edited answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both show the same operation: both branches are moved to the tip (not the start) of their new upstream branch.

- `experiment` is moved on top of `master`

  ```
  git checkout experiment
  git rebase master
  ```
- `branch-A` is moved on top of `branch-B`

  ```
  git checkout branch-A
  git rebase branch-B
  ```

> we want to integrate the changes from branch-B(!!) into branch-A,

That is what `git rebase branch-B` does: it replays commits from `branch-A` on top of `branch-B`, ensuring that any commit of `branch-B` is now part of `branch-A`: changes from `branch-B` are now into (part of the history of) `branch-A`.

Comment: _we want to integrate the changes from branch-B(!!) into branch-A,_

Comment: @RoyiNamir Yes, that is what is done: branch-B is now part of branch-A. The description is accurate.

Comment: I was expecting this : https://i.imgur.com/XZJViqm.jpg . branch b Is AFTER commits in branch A

Comment: @RoyiNamir That would not integrate changes of branch-B into branch-A. That would be the opposite rebase: git checkout branch-B, git rebase branch-A: you would replay branch-B on top of branch-A. Branch-A would now be part of branch-B.

Comment: I'm sorry. I guess I'm missing something fundemental. why in the first eaxmple - the suppose to be merged commit is being applied **at the tip of the beanch** , while in the second example , branch B (which we want to merge/rebase to branch A) - is not being applied to the tip of branch A ?  as in this image : https://i.imgur.com/Vu9ibSB.jpg ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir It depends what you are refereing to as "first example". If we focus on the branch-A/branch-B images, the first images describes the initial setup: 2 branches starting from C1 (there is no merge here). Then a rebase branch-B is done, replaying brnach-A on top of branch-B

Comment: @RoyiNamir Only your git-scm pictures show a merge in the first one. Don't forget the arrows are pointing to the parent of a commit, not to "the next commit".

Comment: The only way I will understand it is if they confused in words: https://i.imgur.com/BPVhSaZ.jpg

Comment: So basically the rebased branch was A ? they wanted to rebase A to B ? if so , then now - I do understand it.

Comment: @RoyiNamir yes: you checkout A, and rebase B, which means "replay commits of A on top of the B HEAD". That is what my edited answer says.

Comment: Thanks for your patience. indeed the line _we want to integrate the changes from branch-B into branch-A, but now by  using rebase_ was the culprit.